# How to get data from google-cloud-firestore in to a global variable?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a web app that generates or view statistics reports. The data will be collected from an android app will get data from google-cloud-firestore(GCF) save this data in variables and make calculations like mean, media, plot etc. The issue I'm having is that I can only view the data from GCF on the console when I try to return data provided or put the data in a global variable the data doesn't appear. I want to know why this happens and also how to solve this issue. I believe is my shortcoming on understanding this technology, I already read the documentation but I don't know what concept I don't understand and doing it wrong. Please let your light of illuminate sages shine a bit upon me.

```js
//firestore
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("./sis-restaurante-firebase-adminsdk-huzz9-7b82544553.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://sis-restaurante.firebaseio.com"
});

var db = admin.firestore();

globalTest = [1,2,3,4]
var giveMyStuff = db.collection("pedidos")
        .onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
            localTest = []
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
              localTest.push(doc.data().statusitem);
              globalTest.push(doc.data().statusitem);
            });
            console.log("Estatus dos pratos: ", localTest.join(", "));  

        }
        );  



console.log(giveMyStuff)
console.log(globalTest)
```

Console Output:
    [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
    Estatus dos pratos:  Em Preparo, Pronto, Em Preparo

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The database APIs are asynchronous and return immediately.  Your console log is executed before the database has time to respond in your callback.  You should only use values from the database after the callback is complete.

Comment: Hi Doug, I didn't completely understand what you said. Let me try to translate it. As the database APIs are asynchronous and return immediately but not as fast as the console.log I need to use the values from the database after the callback is completed. But how do I know when it is completed and I can save the value in a variable that can be used outside the database function?

Comment: You know when it's complete, because your code in the callback will have executed.  You should only use the results in the callback, or if you are certain that it already completed. Your code right now is assuming that the database query is instantaneous, which it is not.

Comment: I understand what you are saying now. But what I need is to get the results in the callback append to a variable that can be used outside the callback function is that possible? Also, thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  That's what you're doing now.  You're just assuming that the data is available before it's actually been populated in the global.